# Rails 3 add virtual attribute dynamically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

My setup: Rails 3.0.9, Ruby 1.9.2

I have my reasons for doing this but what I need is a way to add a virtual attribute to an activerecord resultset dynamically. That means I am not using `attr_accessor` in the model and instead wish to dynamically add virtual attributes to a resultset.

For example,

```
users = User.all
#a user has following attributes: name, email, password
```

What I like to do is say add (without using `attr_accessor`) a virtual attribute `status` to `users`, is that possible?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should do this:

```
users.each do |user|
  user.instance_eval do
    def status
      instance_variable_get("@status")
    end        
    def status=(val) 
      instance_variable_set("@status",val)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: this would not work, as this attribute would not be persisted in the database

Comment: @Tilo: you obviously don't know what is a virtual attribute

Comment: @Tilo: http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes You'll see a virtual attribute is not supposed to be saved in database

Comment: @Tilo: His question is: set dynamically an `attr_accessor`, very clear. Would you mind removing your absurd -1?

Comment: sure, I'm familiar with that Railscast. That can help if you need a virtual attribute just temporarily, e.g. for a form field. But if you want to have a truly dynamic persisted attribute, it won't work. The problem with that is that other sessions might modify a record, thereby modifying the value of a dynamic attribute, but it wouldn't be persisted and the values might end up being different across sessions. Also: the state of a local record may simply become stale. Really depends on what Bob wants here...  If he only need non-persisted temporary attributes, your answer is perfect.

Comment: I removed it, and +1 for yours

Comment: @apneadiving, you are correct in his interpretation of my question, I'll try out your solution later tonight when I have some time. Tilo, thanks for your effort as well.

Answer (score 2):

you can do the following:

add an attribute "extras" which will be accessed as a Hash, and which will store any additional / dynamic attributes -- and then tell Rails to persist that Hash via JSON in ActiveRecord or Mongo or whatever you use

e.g.:

```
class AddExtrasToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :users, :extras, :text    # do not use a binary type here! (rails bug)
  end
  ...
end
```

then in the model add a statement to "serialize" that new attribute -- e.g. that means it's persisted as JSON

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
...
serialize :extras
...
end
```

You can now do this:

```
   u = User.find 3

   u.extras[:status] = 'valid'
   u.save
```

You can also add a bit of magic to the User model, to look at the extras Hash if it gets a method_missing() call

See also:
  Google "Rails 3 serialize"

Comment: you're not defining an `attr_accessor` behavior here.

Comment: re-read Bob's question - he explicitly says that he does not want to use attr_accessor

Comment: he says he doesn't want to set `attr_accessor` in the model, which is quite different

Comment: your hash has nothing virtual. I don't say your answer is bad, just your judgment on mine was unjustified

Answer (score 1):

If your attributes are read-only, you can also add them by selecting them in your database query. Fields which appear in the SQL result result will automatically be add as attributes.

Examples:

```
User.find_by_sql('users.*, (...) AS status')
User.select('users.*, joined_table.status').join(...)
```

With these examples you'll have all `User` attributes and an additional `status` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do:

```
users.each { |user| user.class_eval { attr_accessor :status } }
```

All `users` will have `user.status` and `user.status = :new_status` available.